# How to create an Excel sheet using xlwt in django

Tags: python, django, xlwt

[image]I want to create an excel file like below.But I do not know , how to implement it.Excel sheet contains headers,sub headers and sub-sub headers.

Actually the excel sheet is generated based on the `from date` and `to date`.If there is three months between `from date` and `to date`,these three months should be shown as columns in the excel sheet.

```
        from_date = request.POST.get('f_date')
        to_date = request.POST.get('t_date')
        file_name = "Report"
        content_disposition = 'attachment; filename="' + file_name + '.xlsx"'
        title = str(file_name) + " {} TO {}".format(from_date, to_date)

        header = ['Plant Locality', 'Plant', 'Product', 'UOM', 'Previous Year FTP', 'Previous Year YTP']
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to create this excel sheet using xlwt?